# How to get android app size like other App Manager application

Tags: java, android

i try to get application information especially it size. But i can't get actual size like, i just get size of youtube about 20MB but when i see in Setting > Applications it size is 70MB.

And i wonder how other application like **App Manager** can get the correct application information?

I tried to use Android API, like this `File(context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(packageN‌​ame, 0).sourceDir).length();`

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: i try to use Android API, like this `File(context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0).sourceDir).length();`